# Move links div aside h1, above tagline p

Tags: html, css, web

I have a page that has CSS media queries in it, and I was requested to do this:

Mobile layout:
[image: mobile layout]

Desktop layout:
[image: desktop layout]

Now, the HTML code is placed like this:

```
<div id="content">
  <h1>the title</h1>
  <p>this is the tagline of the site</p>
  <ul>
    <li>link 1</li>
    <li>link 2</li>
    <li>link 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I'm having quite a problem trying to achieve the desktop layout. I tried wrapping `<h1>` and `<p>` in a `<div>` and style it with `float: left`, but it didn't look as requested (the tagline is wider). I also tried with `position: absolute` for the `<ul>`, but also didn't look as requested (make the `#content` wider is not an option).

Do you have any suggestions to achieve this without using javascript?

**Update:**

I've uploaded the code to [my Koding](http://noquierouser-prime.koding.com/h1tagline/index.html) so you can see what I'm actually doing. [This is the CSS](http://noquierouser-prime.koding.com/h1tagline/styles.css). I'm also using [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/).

The problem I'm having now is what do the different browsers show:
[image: what browsers show]

I think the problem might be in how do the browsers calculate the tagline's width, but as you can try with the code, if you make the tagline's text shorter, it looks more like Opera's rendering.

Have I stumbled with a bug or am I making some mistake in my CSS?

Comment: Can you share the css you have?

Comment: I'm trying with this code now. It works well in Chrome and Opera, but Firefox is not displaying it well.

http://jsfiddle.net/J76Xr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `float: left` in the `<h1>` and in the `<p>`. Not in the `<ul>`.
After that, set the `<p>` width to 100% and set a top-margin to the `<ul>`.

To get all the `<li>` side by side you set them to `display: inline`.

Comment: This helped me to get the results I got in http://jsfiddle.net/J76Xr/1/, with a little tweak.

In Firefox wasn't showing well, so I made the `<ul>` to display correctly with `display: inline-block`.

I don't know if there's room for improving this, because I had to add an additional `<div>` and use a clearfix hack.

Comment: I used Chrome to get to the solution.

Comment: Now I'm having some problems in all browsers. If the tagline is too short, the `<ul>` doesn't place itself aside the `<h1>`.  
  
Also, in Firefox (so far), when the tagline is "the right size", the container `<div>` gets wider. I'll post screenshots soon to see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the `ul` has enough room to hold the `li`'s next to each other.

```
width: 1million px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not terribly elegant, but you could try something like this...

**CSS**

```
h1, ul, li {
    float: left;
}
h1 {
    height: 48px;
}
p {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 48px;
}
ul {
    padding-top: 12px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jTych/)**